# WPF: What distinguishes a Dependency Property from a regular CLR Property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

In WPF, what, really, does it mean to be a "dependency property"?

I read Microsoft's [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), but it's not really sinking in for me. In part that article says:

> Styles and templates are two of the chief motivating scenarios for using dependency properties. Styles are particularly useful for setting properties that define application user interface (UI). Styles are typically defined as resources in XAML. Styles interact with the property system because they typically contain "setters" for particular properties, as well as "triggers" that change a property value based on the real-time value for another property.

And then the example code is this:

```
<Style x:Key="GreenButtonStyle">
  <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
....
<Button Style="{StaticResource GreenButtonStyle}">I am green!</Button>
```

But I'm not getting what is special about this.  Does it just imply, that when I set `Style` on the button to the given style, that I am actually setting `Background` implicitly?  Is that the crux of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In WPF, what, really, does it mean to be a "dependency property"?

In order to be a dependency property, the property must actually be defined as a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), statically, on the class.  The dependency property system is very different than a standard CLR property.

Dependency properties are handled very differently, though.  A type defines a dependency property **statically**, and provides a default value.  The runtime actually doesn't generate a value for an instance until it's needed.  This provides one benefit - the property doesn't exist until requested for a type, so you can have a large number of properties without overhead.

This is what makes the styling work property, but is also important to allow attached properties, property "inheritance" through the visual tree, and many other things WPF relies on.

For example, take the `DataContext` dependency property.  Typically, you set the `DataContext` dependency property for a Window or a UserControl.  All of the controls within that Window, by default, "inherit" their parent's `DataContext` proeprty automatically, which allows you to specify data bindings for controls.  With a standard CLR property, you'd need to define that DataContext for every control in the window, just to get binding to work properly.

Comment: Ah, good information, thanks.  Ok, so how does the magic work, that allows a child control to get access to the DataContext of the ancestor Window ?  Can you give me a link to a writeup of this?

Comment: @Cheeso: Search for "Property Value Inheritance" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx  There's a bit on this on that page...

Answer (score 29):

Here's the explanation for how dependency properties work that I always wished someone had written for me.  It's incomplete and quite possibly wrong, but it will help you develop enough of an understanding of them that you can will be able to grasp the documentation that you read.

Dependency properties are property-like values that are get and set via methods of the `DependencyObject` class.  They can (and generally do) look very much like CLR properties, but they're not.  And this gets to the first confusing thing about them.  A dependency property is really made up of a couple of components.

Here's an example:

`Document` is a property of the `RichTextBox` object.  It's a real CLR property.  That is to say, it's got a name, a type, a getter, and a setter, just like any other CLR property.  But unlike "normal" properties, the `RichTextBox` property doesn't merely get and set a private value inside the instance.  Internally, it's implemented like this:

```
public FlowDocument Document
{
   get { return (FlowDocument)GetValue(DocumentProperty); }
   set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
}
```

When you set `Document`, the value you passed in gets passed to `SetValue`, along with `DocumentProperty`.  And what is *that*?  And how does `GetValue` get its value?  And ...why?

First the what.  There's a static property defined on the `RichTextBox` named `DocumentProperty`.  When this property is declared, it's done like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty DocumentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Document",
    typeof(FlowDocument), 
    typeof(RichTextBox));
```

The `Register` method, in this case, tells the dependency property system that `RichTextBox` - the type, not the instance - now has a dependency property named `Document` of type `FlowDocument`.  This method stores this information...somewhere.  Where, exactly, is an implementation detail that's hidden from us.

When the setter for the `Document` property calls `SetValue`, the `SetValue` method looks at the `DocumentProperty` argument, verifies that it's really a property that belongs to `RichTextBox` and that `value` is the right type, and then stores its new value...somewhere.  The documentation for `DependencyObject` is coy on this implementation detail, because you don't really need to know it.  In my mental model of how this stuff works, I assume there's a property of type `Dictionary<DependencyProperty, object>` that's private to the `DependencyObject`, so derived classes (like `RichTextBox`) can't see it but `GetValue` and `SetValue` can update it.  But who knows, maybe it's written on parchment by monks.

At any rate, this value is now what's called a "local value," which is to say it's a value that's local to this specific `RichTextBox`, just like an ordinary property.

The point of *all* this is:

1. CLR code doesn't need to know that a property is a dependency property.  It looks exactly like any other property.  You *can* call `GetValue` and `SetValue` to get and set it, but unless you're doing something with the dependency property system, you probably don't need to.
2. Unlike a normal property, something other than the object that it belongs to can be involved in getting and setting it.  (You could do this with reflection, conceivably, but reflection is slow.  Looking things up in dictionaries is fast.)
3. This something - which is the dependency property system - essentially sits between an object and its dependency properties.  And it can do *all kinds of things*.

What kinds of things?  Well, let's look at some use cases.

**Binding.**  When you bind to a property, it has to be a dependency property.  This is because the `Binding` object doesn't actually set properties on the target, it calls `SetValue` on the target object.

**Styles.**  When you set an object's dependency property to a new value, `SetValue` tells the style system that you've done so.  That's how triggers work:  they don't find out that a property's value has changed through magic, the dependency property system tells them.

**Dynamic resources.**  If you write XAML like `Background={DynamicResource MyBackground}`, you can change the value of the `MyBackground` resource, and the background of the object referencing it gets updated.  This isn't magic either; the dynamic resource calls `SetValue`.

**Animations.**  Animations work by manipulating property values.  Those have to be dependency properties, because the animation is calling `SetValue` to get at them.

**Change notification.**  When you register a dependency property, you can also specify a function that `SetValue` will call when it sets the property's value.

**Value inheritance.**  When you register a dependency property, you can specify that it participate in property value inheritance.  When you call `GetValue` to get the value of an object's dependency property, `GetValue` looks to see if there's a local value.  If there's not, it traverses up the chain of parent objects looking at *their* local values for that property.

This is how it is that you can set the `FontFamily` on a `Window` and magically (I'm using that word a lot) every control in the window uses the new font.  Also, it's how it is that you can have hundreds of controls in a window without each of them having a `FontFamily` member variable to track their font (since they don't have local values) but you can still set the `FontFamily` on any one control (because of the seekrit hidden dictionary of values that every `DependencyObject` has).

Comment: This is very important: "You could do this with reflection, but reflection is slow. Looking things up in dictionaries is fast". This and the changed event are 2 good reasons for the dependency properties.

Comment: I agree:  If I were to rewrite this, it would emphasize the performance issues in play a lot more.  Most of the oddness and complexity of the dependency property system come from the fact that if it weren't fast, it would break WPF.  Also, I'd add value inheritance to your list of good reasons.  Value inheritance is enormously important to WPF.  And value inheritance + change notification = magic.

Comment: The best explanation I've seen for this topic!

Comment: *"Binding. When you bind to a property, it has to be a dependency property. This is because the Binding object doesn't actually set properties on the target, it calls SetValue on the target object."* You can bind to an ordinary CLR property, although you will almost certainly want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 9):

It may be helpful to understand what problem the dependency property is trying to solve.

If we put the Binding, Animation and the Change Event model to one side as they've been discussed in other answers, the benefit is memory usage and thus scalability to host many thousand WPF objects in a window.

If a window contains 1000 `Label` objects with each `Label` object having the usual `Foreground`, `Background`, `FontFamily`, `FontSize`, `FontWeight`, etc., then traditionally this would consume memory because each property would have a private backing field to store the value.

Most applications will change only a few properties, the majority of which will be left at their default values.  Basically very wasteful and redundant information (each object just holding the same default values in memory)

This is where dependency properties are different.

```
// Lets register the Dependency Property with a default value of 20.5
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MyWPFControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(20.5, ColWitdhPropChanged));

public double ColumnWidth
{
  get { return (double)GetValue(ColumnWidthProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ColumnWidthProperty, value); }
}
```

There is no private backing field.  When the dependency property is registered a default value can be specified.  So in most cases the returned value from `GetValue` is the default value that has only been stored the once to cover all instances of the `Label` object across all windows of your application.

When a dependency property is set using the `SetValue` it stores the non-default value in a collection identified by the object instance, to be returned in all subsequent `GetValue` calls.

This storage method will therefore only consume memory for the properties of the WPF objects that have changed from the default value. i.e. only the differences from the default value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple/fundamental difference - Change Notification: Changes to Dependency Properties are reflected/refreshed in UI on changes whereas CLR properties don't.

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWPF.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPF"
        Title="About WPF Unleashed" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Background="OrangeRed"
        >
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainForm}">
        <!-- Bind to Dependency Property -->
        <Label Name="txtCount1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="{Binding ElementName=MainForm, Path=Count1, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <!-- Bind to CLR Property -->
        <Label Name="txtCount2" Content="{Binding ElementName=MainForm, Path=Count2, Mode=OneWay}"></Label>

        <!-- Bind to Dependency Property (Using DataContext declared in StackPanel) -->
        <Label Name="txtCount3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="{Binding Count1}" />

        <!-- Child Control binding to Dependency Property (Which propagates down element tree) -->
        <local:UserControl1 />

        <!-- Child Control binding to CLR Property (Won't work as CLR properties don't propagate down element tree) -->
        <local:UserControl2 />

        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtCount1, Path=Content}" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtCount2, Path=Content}" ></TextBox>

        <Button Name="btnButton1" Click="btnButton1_Click_1">Increment1</Button>
        <Button Name="btnButton2" Click="btnButton1_Click_2">Increment2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="SampleWPF.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Count1}" ></Label>
        <!--
        <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Count1}"></Label>
        -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="SampleWPF.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Count2}" ></Label>
        <!--
        <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Count2}"></Label>
        -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind here (To declare the CLR and Dependency property):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    namespace SampleWPF
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty Count1Property;
            private int _Count2 = 2;
            public int Count2
            {
                get { return _Count2; }
                set { _Count2 = value; }
            }
            public MainWindow()
            {
                return;
            }
            static MainWindow()
            {
                // Register the property
                MainWindow.Count1Property = 
                    DependencyProperty.Register("Count1",
                    typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCount1Changed)));
            }
            // A .NET property wrapper (optional)
            public int Count1
            {
                get { return (int)GetValue(MainWindow.Count1Property); }
                set { SetValue(MainWindow.Count1Property, value); }
            }
            // A property changed callback (optional)
            private static void OnCount1Changed(
              DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

            }
            private void btnButton1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Count1++;
            }
            private void btnButton1_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Count2++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another feature provided by Dependency Properties is value inheritance - value set in top level elements propagates down the element tree - In following example taken from http://en.csharp-online.net, FontSize and FontStyle declared on "Window" tag is applied to all child elements underneath:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  Title="About WPF Unleashed" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
  FontSize="30" FontStyle="Italic"
  Background="OrangeRed">
  <StackPanel>
    <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White">
      WPF Unleashed (Version 3.0)
    </Label>
    <Label>© 2006 SAMS Publishing</Label>
    <Label>Installed Chapters:</Label>
    <ListBox>
      <ListBoxItem>Chapter 1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Chapter 2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10">Help</Button>
      <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10">OK</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StatusBar>You have successfully registered this product.</StatusBar>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**References:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part-1
http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Property_Value_Inheritance