# Binding to a usercontrol's DependencyProperty is not calling the setter

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties, windows-phone-8.1

My page xaml:

```
<header:DefaultText x:Name="header" HeaderText="{Binding Resources.HeaderTitle}"/>
```

My DefaultText.cs DependencyProperty:

```
    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set
        {   //This part is never called when binding, but it is with static text
            SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);
            SetText(value);
        }
    }

    public readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(DefaultText), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

My problem is that when I set the HeaderText property with a binding the setter isn't called, but when I use a normal string without binding it is called.

I already tried the answers of similar questions like: [WPF Binding to variable / DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547591/wpf-binding-to-variable-dependencyproperty)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: XAML property declarations not being set via Setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836076/wpf-xaml-property-declarations-not-being-set-via-setters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XAML binding internally doesn't call your Setter method but sets the dependency property's value directly, as is pointed out [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The WPF XAML processor uses property system methods for dependency
>   properties when loading binary XAML and processing attributes that are
>   dependency properties. This effectively bypasses the property
>   wrappers. When you implement custom dependency properties, you must
>   account for this behavior and should avoid placing any other code in
>   your property wrapper other than the property system methods GetValue
>   and SetValue.

What you need to do is register a callback method that fires whenever the dependency property changes:

```
public static DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "HeaderText", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(DefaultText), 
    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, PropertyChangedCallback)
);

private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // this is the method that is called whenever the dependency property's value has changed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and explanation, it still doesn't appear to work, could I be missing something else?
The PropertyChangedCallback does get called when I'm not using a binding but not when using the binding.

Comment: Maybe your dependency property isn't updated at all, try adding `{Binding ..., Mode=TwoWay}` to the binding to force updating in both directions?

Comment: I changed it to `HeaderText="{Binding Resources.HeaderTitle, Mode=TwoWay}"` and it still doesn't appear to work. The binding does work when I'm using it on a normal control like TextBlock.Text instead of a user control.

Comment: Another idea: Can you check if `Resources.HeaderTitle` (or whatever you're binding to) really contains some data at the moment the binding is evaluated? If the binding value is equal to the dependency property's default value (in your case, `string.Empty`), the callback will not fire.

Comment: That was the problem, the translator appeared to have missed that one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used so many DependencyProperties in the last few years but never met this problem. I honestly thought it'd call the setter. So thank you for the PropertyChangedCallback!